# VBA Freeze Panes Function Hides Some Left Columns (Unintended) even after programatically scrolling to the Left

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to apply formatting to a large sheet of data using VBA involving grouping columns, and freezing panes. I am running into an issue where the freeze panes function activates when the sheet is scrolled to the right a bit, thus hiding some left columns.

I have tried adding the following code in front of the cell selection and `FreezePanes = True` command.

1. `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1`

   `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1`
2. `Application.Goto Reference:=Sheet1.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True`
3. This worked, but causes the incorrect cell to be selected as I am using a variable in the cells object.

   ```
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, 
   ColumnLevels:=1
   ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
   ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
   Cells(8, buildCol + 1).Select
   ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, 
   ColumnLevels:=1
   ```

Comment: Instead of Freezing the window, you may want to look into splitting it. ex: `ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 5`

Comment: Thanks! I have found this to work well:                                                           With ActiveWindow
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitColumn = buildCol
        .SplitRow = 7
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will freeze row 1 and column 1. Maybe use something like this in there.

```
Sub FreezeCell()
    With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 1
    .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```